# Search for CharSequences between two CharSeqeunces (Java)

Tags: java, search, charsequence

first of all I want to say, that I'm a noobie in Java. (Sorry if the answer is that easy).
I have a String, which contains following text:

```
String htmlContent = "DienstagfÃ¤lltMittwochfÃ¤llt";
```

Now I have 3 CharSequences:

```
CharSequence dt = "Dienstag";
CharSequence mt = "Mittwoch";
CharSequence keyword = "fÃ¤llt";
```

I want search

```
fÃ¤llt
```

between the other 2 CharSequences. I shouldn't find

```
fÃ¤llt
```

after the CharSequence

```
Mittwoch
```

Is there a method or something else? And when not, how I can realize my idea?
An example wouldn't be bad :).

My code now:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TextScanner {

   public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
       URL url = new URL("http://mpg-vertretungsplan.de/w/18/w00023.htm");
       InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
       String line = null;
       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
       while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
         sb.append(line);
       }
       String htmlContent = sb.toString();
       System.out.println(htmlContent);
     CharSequence dt="Dienstag";
     CharSequence mt="Mittwoch";
     CharSequence keyword="fÃ¤llt";
     boolean found = htmlContent.contains(keyword);
     if(found==true){
         System.out.println("Es gibt eine Fehlstunde!");
     }else{
         System.out.println("Es gibt keine Fehlstunde!");
     }

   }
}
```

I want that the answer is also false, if

```
keyword
```

is after

```
mt
```

in the string:

```
String htmlContent2 = "DienstagMittwochfÃ¤llt";
```

Comment: as for every `HTML` parsing as `String` question, the better way would be to use a propper html parser instead of handling the `html` as a simple `String`.

Comment: Even if the String was just plain text, how would you do that?

Comment: I changed my question, maybe it's now more general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`String.indexOf(String substr)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) to get the position of the two delimiters in the `String`, then use [`String.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) to get what's between them.

Note that `String.indexOf(String substr)` returns the starting position of the substring, so to compute the `beginIndex` you'll need to add the first delimiter's length.
Also, those methods work on `String`s rather than `CharSequence`, so you'll have to convert them with `.toString()`.

Once you've retrieved that substring, use `.contains(CharSequence substr)` as you currently do to check if it contains the searched `CharSequence`.

You can see it in action [here](https://ideone.com/RVLpCR).

Comment: But it has to be a CharSequence, because my text hasn't any placeholders.

Comment: What do you mean about placeholders? You can easily convert a `CharSequence` to `String` using its `.toString()` method.

Comment: I meant that the String hasn't space between each CharSequence. I changed the String in the question to show it. And yes, it only should show me true or wrong.

Comment: It doesn't matter, maybe you understood my use of "delimiters" as "space delimiters", but I meant the two specified words. Have you checked my example? You could remove every space from the data string and it would still work.

Comment: @alexanders916 I've edited my example to make it more clear. Also after some thinking my method isn't so inefficient. I may add a regular expression solution if you're interested, it's another good way to solve your problem, but it requires a lot more learning if you're not familiar with regular expressions

Comment: Maybe I just made a mistake once. One time I couldn't find a String because I thought that a String could be only find, when this String is seperated in his ParentString. Thank you, for explaining it!

Answer (score 0):

```
htmlContent.substring(htmlContent.indexOf("Mittwoch")).contains("fÃ¤llt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use many methods to check if the sentence is exist or not, for example:

***Using Contains()***

```
String htmlContent = "DienstagfÃ¤lltMittwochfÃ¤llt";
String myString = "fÃ¤llt";
if(htmlContent.contains(myString)) //contains method return true or false
{
System.out.println("myString is exist")
}
```

another method is ***using indexOf***

```
if(htmlContent.indexOf(myString)>1)//returns an Integer if it is -1 that's mean the string doesn't exist, otherwise the string is exist
{
System.out.println("myString is exist")
}
```